# How to simply start mapping in R?

Tags: r, data.table, mapping, cartography

For the first time, I want to do mapping in R, something very basic to start with.

For example, draw the map of a country and add points according to GPS coordinates that I have in a datatable.

I thought it would be simple but it looks more complicated than expected.

How to start? Which package do you recommend me to use?

I found a lot of package to do mapping, but I can't decide which one would be the most suitable for my case.

THANKS

Comment: I suggest sf package.

Comment: ok thank you, i will focus on this package

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your starting point, I would say – if you're familiar with ggplot2 already, I would go for the corresponding tutorial here: https://ggplot2-book.org/maps.html

Other than that, https://bookdown.org/robinlovelace/geocompr/adv-map.html is a very good resource for anything geospatial in R. It focuses on tmap instead of ggplot2 though.

Comment: ok thank you, i will focus on this option